# Xamarin.Forms Previewer does not show up in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am developing app using Xamarin in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. I go to View -> Other Windows but there is no Xamarin.Forms Previewer. I am pretty sure It was still here last night.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Does anyone know what is happening? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so I figured it out myself. It's kind of easy. I am posting here just in case someone will need it in the future. We just need to go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates and then enable Xamarin.forms Previewer and done!
[image: Screen shoot]

Answer (score 5):

In **VS 2017**, Xamarin.Forms Previewer is attached to the editor window. Just we need to expand by clicking on **Expand Pane** button as shown in the image.

[image].

Comment: i dont have this tab there

Comment: @BluePrint If you are using VS 2019, Please check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66650853/10335860. It's deprecated in  Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.8 and replaced by the XAML Hot Reload feature in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.9.