# Xamarin Forms Previewer is missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

[image]

The issue occurred on Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.9.1.

The VS version mentioned above was just downloaded. I am trying to develop a mobile app, but the Xamarin Forms Previewer is missing and I can not enable it from the Option Tools.

For more information, please see the attached files.

Can you help me with a solution?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The XAML Previewer has been deprecated in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.8, and replaced by the XAML Hot Reload feature in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.9.

For now, it use the Hot Reload insead and provide a live visual tree to receive a real-time view of your running XAML code. It shows a tree view of the UI elements of your running Xamarin.Forms application.

When you debug you project, by default, it appears on the IDE's left. If you don't see it, use **Debug > Windows > Live Visual Tree** to show it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if Xamarin Previewer will be implemented again in the future ?

Comment: There is no announcement for Xamarin Previewer which would be implemented again recently.

Comment: MSFT: can you please un-deprecate XAML Previewer? It is much more useful than XAML Hot Reload when doing initial design work of a user interface. XAML Hot Reload is more useful for debugging, but not for initial designing of a UI.

Comment: Would like to see Blend or the WPF-design experience treat Xamarin XAML as a first class citizen for designing the initial UI, like @David writes.

Answer (score -1):

I also face the same problem today in visual studio 16.9.1. I am also not able to enable it from anywhere in Visual Studio

Comment: Zinveliu: agreed. I can't believe they deprecated XAML Previewer, when it's much better than XAML Hot Reload with regard to doing initial design work on a UI. With XAML Hot Reload, I have to run the app and navigate to the page-of-interest before I can do any serious work on the UI of the page. It's horrible.

Comment: DV. Consider answering questions with an actual answer that helps others. This barely belongs to the comment section. Check SO's instructions on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).