# How to quick preview XamarinForms Controls or Pages with Visual Studio 16.9 or later? (Best way)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, design-time

I used the **Xamarin Forms Previewer** to develop Xamarin Forms views (pages, controls). But unfortunately Microsoft removed the Xamarin Forms Previewer since update to **Visual Studio version 16.9**.

So what to use instead? The **Xamarin Live Player** also not available anymore.
Of course I can start my app on my device and use the **Hot Reload** feature to see my Control in action, but that is not the quick way, because every time I have to navigate to the page and get the state I want to see performing my control.

I just want to get following:

- Quick/simple visualization of my blank XAML - aware of design time and also supporting the XAML extension `d:...` (e.g. `d:IsVisible="True"`).
- Live visual changes while changing the XAML using Design-Time-ViewModel instance.
- No need to connect my device or start an emulator.
- All I want is a quick rendered preview of current view.

Do I really have to create an additional project with a simple activity only bootstrapping my current page to edit?

Comment: Hot Reload is the official way to preview/layout apps (which sucks as hell)

Comment: Is it helpful for you ?

Comment: MSFT: can you please un-deprecate XAML Previewer? It is much more useful than XAML Hot Reload when doing initial design work of a user interface. XAML Hot Reload is more useful for debugging, but not for initial designing of a UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no announcement for Xamarin Previewer which would be implemented again recently.At this time you just could use `Live Visual Tree`,refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66650853/10768653

or rolls back the Visual Studio version.

Comment: This is a huge misstep. XAML Previewer is much better than XAML Hot Reload when it comes to doing the initial legwork of designing a UI.